# Google Developer Console Doesn't List Mail API

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-imap

The [Google Developer Consoles](https://console.developers.google.com/) (even the [old version](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect)) no longer lists the Mail API in the list of available APIs.

I'm trying to develop a web application which acts on behalf of users to manage their Gmail, like [Mailbox](http://www.mailboxapp.com/). This requires using the [Gmail IMAP API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview) with [XOAUTH2 authentication](https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol) with an [OAuth 2.0 access token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2). The documentation instructs [provisioning OAuth 2.0 token](https://developers.google.com/gmail/xoauth2_protocol#using_oauth_20) with a `https://mail.google.com/` scope. Provisioning [credentials for a web application](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer) then requesting a token with this scope yields a 403 response with an `accessNotConfigured` error. There are options in the developer console for configuring other APIs, but there is no option to configure access for the Mail API.

Attempting to provision the mail scope in the [Google OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) using their client credentials works correctly and the resulting access token can be used to access Gmail IMAP with XOAUTH2.

Have Google disabled OAuth 2.0 authentication for Mail using new credentials, or is it just hidden? I can't find a way to contact them and ask for Mail API access.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: Ruby. Shouldn't matter though. Using my own credentials in the OAuth 2.0 playground gives the same result. Update: I just tried the playground again and it seems to work? Let me investigate some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create any client id it doesn't matter what API you select. When you make the authentication request send the scope of https://mail.google.com/.  That will get you the access token you need to login to the imap server.

Comment: Nope, sorry, I've tried this as described in the question: I get the 403 accessNotConfigured when trying to fetch the access token. Have you attempted this recently?

Comment: yup just made a tutorial on it to test it but its in C#.  so it wont help you much.  http://www.daimto.com/how-to-access-gmail-with-c-net/

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I poked it some more and got it working. Must've been something in a library I was using, doing it in bare metal works great.